# Remote control for iTunes?

Tags: itunes

I want a program like the [Remote](http://www.apple.com/itunes/remote/) app for the iPhone, that will run natively on Windows, OSX and Linux.  Any suggestions?

Comment: So, just to clarify, you've got an existing iTunes library that you want to access from other Win/OSX/Linux machines on your network, and have the audio/video output on the machine with the iTunes library?

Comment: @arathorn - That's correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not fancy, but using VNC or a remote desktop app of some kind would work.

There is [iTunesRemote](http://itunesremote.sourceforge.net/), in the downloads section it looks like they have apps for OS X, Windows, and Linux. The version numbers are pretty low though.

[Remote iTunes](http://www.delicioussuite.com/technology/deliciousfun/applications/remote_itunes.html) looks like a decent OS X app. There's also [iTunes Remote Control](http://www.them.ws/itrc/), while being OS X only is open source. So, it may provide a solution for someone enterprising enough to dig into it.

If you have a supported phone and bluetooth you can probably use [Salling Clicker](http://www.salling.com/Clicker) on OS X and Windows.

Here's a [hardware solution](http://www.tripplite.com/EN/products/model.cfm?txtSeriesID=517&txtModelID=3910) for Windows and OS X.

There doesn't seem to be much in the way of Windows or Linux apps to do this however. iTunesRemote looks to be the best option I can find.

Comment: I looked at Remote iTunes and didn't seem to work for me.  I guess maybe I'll try iTunes Remote Control and see what that does.  Thanks.

Comment: OS X only, but seems to work pretty well:  http://www.tuneconnect.net/

Comment: Post should be updated some links are not working anymore.

Comment: Nothing seems to work here

Answer (score 3):

[**Tunes Remote SE**](http://code.google.com/p/tunesremote-se/) is the way to go!

It's just perfect, cross-platform (developped in Java), with an UI similar to iTunes, let's you see the whole library and covers (not just "play/next/pause"), and even Genius mixes!

Comment: This deserves way more upvotes - works perfectly for me on Linux.

Comment: Yeah, this is great on Ubuntu. Well. Pretty good at least. Pairing was confusing (the paired library didn't appear to show up in the list until I restarted after successfully pairing).

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question, but have you tried AnyRemote?  It has a Java client that should be platform-independent.  If you're a Linux user, I have seen it in the Debian repositories, and their web site says they have KDE and Gnome front-ends.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the accepted answer options and not finding anything I liked, I came across **[TuneConnect](http://www.tuneconnect.net/)** (version 2 was out at the time of writing).

Free, open source and it does exactly what I wanted to do. The only downside is it's OS X-only, but at least it's a good looking OS X app that fits nicely in to the OS X workflow.

Comment: Downside: you need to install a server on the targeted machine. And because of this, you can only control an OS X machine from an OS X machine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm up and running now - controlling an iMac 10.9 from a Linux KDE Neon -  using [iTunesRemote](https://github.com/drshriveer/iTunesRemote) java based client/server stack [image]. I was very pleasantly surprised that it compiles and runs. The ancient macos machine even runs the bytecode compiled by my modern linuxbox. It also runs when it compiles on the mac (naturally).

Main issues:

- User must run a one line command on terminal of *both* machines
- Server must be macos
- User must hard-code and then compile to statically configure the IP address of the Mac server (in the client app that runs on linuxbox workstation)

I just ssh into the mac then run tmux / screen and close my term. Maybe later I will setup startup / cron or similar.

If I am feeling energetic I may add a field to configure the server dynamically and do a pull request. For now I am up and running. It also pulls the song name.

Answer (score -1):

If you are just wanting to play itunes shared libraries, you can just use itunes on a computer and connect to a shared library.  I know it is not a small remote like app, but it works.

Unless you mean control what is playing on the computer containing the itunes library from another computer?  That I do not know what solutions are available.